# How can I find the slip speed of a slip ring induction motor without knowing the rotor speed (rated RPM)

Tags: motor, ac, three-phase, induction-motor

The Rotor of a 4 pole, 50hz slip ring induction motor has a resistance of 5ohm per phase and inductance of 150mH per phase. Calculate the slip speed at which max torque occurs.

I have used Ns = 120f/p to find the synchronous speed, being 1500RPM, but I cannot calculate the Slip speed without knowing the rated RPM of the motor.

Is there a way to calculate this using the given information?

UPDATE:
I believe this is the answer.

ns = 120f/p
     = 120x50/4
     = 1500 rpm

fr = X/2piL
   = 5/(2pi x 0.150)
   = 5.3hz (or rpm?)

Slip% = fr/f
          = 5.3/50
          = 0.106

Slip speed = slip% x ns
                  = 0.106 x 1500
                  = 159rpm at 10.6% slip (0.106x100)

Comment: The proper formula for synchronous speed is Ns=120f/p.

Comment: Yes, sorry I must have typed it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Homework, I guess, a theoretical one which assumes ideal stator and no substantial saturation nor stray inductance effects.

The general induction motor theory tells: In that ideal case max. torque occurs at slip=R/X where R is one phase resistance (=load + rotor wire) and X=one phase rotor reactance. Actually also negative slip = -(R/X) is valid for max torque; that has meaning for generators.

Comment: I think I have it now. 

= R/X
= 5/0.150
= 33.33

Rated RPM = 1500-33.33 = 1466.67

S% = ns - n/ ns x100
S% = (1500-1466.67)/1500 x100
S% = 2.2%

Does this look correct?

Comment: @Dexterdave Your comment was only "I think I have it now" + nothing else, when I wrote OK. Your calculation is crap. X=6,28fL, that's not 0.15  Slip  as number is between 0 and 1,  slip=1 means stopped, 0 means = sync speed.

Comment: @Dexterdave Im sorry, but I must tell you seem to use numbers very liberally, you insert them to nice looking formulas randomly without thinking their meanings. That's a big obstacle in front of succesful calculations and engineering competence. Start by fixing this. A good beginning is to know that it's useless to add or subtract quantities  which have different dimensions. You subtracted from 1500 RPM a bare number 33.33. That was the 2nd error, your 33.33 was already nonsense.

Comment: Yes, Im new to the site and accidentally posted before I had finished my reply when I pressed enter. Sorry about that. Im not an engineering student, but an apprentice electrician, so these calculations are all a bit above my head.
Thanks for trying to help anyway.

Comment: @Dexterdave then you have something that many of us have never got: Practical skills starting from how to use common tools and equipment + knowing common parts and materials. Do not give up! Find a local  tutor who shows to you some math things which are needed in calculations around the electricity.